# resize synchronously jPanel components

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, layout-manager

I have a `JFrame` as follows:

```
-------------------------|
|JFrame                  |
|                        |
|  |---------------------|
|  |JScrollPane          |
|  | |jXTaskPaneContainer|
|  | |jXTaskPane         |
|  | | |-----------------|
|  | | |jPanel1          |
|  | | |-----------------|
-------------------------|
```

Below you can see the layout of `jPanel1`:

```
|  label1   | (without title) | label2   | label3    | <--labelPanel+BoxLayout
--------------------------------------------------------
| comboBox1 |   comboBox2     |textField1|textField2 | <--controlPanel+BoxLayout
```

For `jXTaskPaneContainer` and `jXTaskPane` I am using `VerticalLayout`.

The goal that I want to achieve is get a resizable `JFrame` with components.

Everything is working ok except `labelPanel` components.

As a space of between `jLabels`. I am using `jlabels` (with EmptyBorder).

When I am resizing `JFrame` the `jPanel1` components resizing not synchronously as follows:

```
|  label1   |   (without title) | label2   | label3    |
--------------------------------------------------------
|     comboBox1    |     comboBox2         |   textField1      | textField2|
```

The result that I want to see: as `label1` the title of `comboBox1`, `label2` defines `textField1`,... I cannot synchronously resize them.

If you have some suggestions please share with me.

Comment: Tip:  Don't mention your IDE when the question is about code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BoxLayout will give its components as much room as they need. JLabels will try to stay as small as possible, whereas JComboBoxes will try to spread out.

You have two options: either futz with the maximum and preferred size of your JLabels, or just use a layout that makes components as large as possible- GridLayout comes to mind.

In fact, what you're describing sounds like a GridLayout on jPanel1, with no need for labelPanel or controlPanel.

Comment: Thank you. Your description is right. I fixed my problem.